# IE8 BHO tab problem

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, bho

I am developing an IE8 BHO in C#. One of the functions of the BHO is to maintain a list of website pairs visited by the user. I add the pair (url1, url2) to the list if the user visits url2 by clicking on a link present at url1. I will be using this info to show the ie history in a nice way as opposed to the default behaviour of showing a long list of visited websites (something along the lines of the Firefox addon [Voyage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14650/) ). In my BHO, I am currently using the [BeforeNavigate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) event to find the URL the user is going to visit. This works fine as long as the page is opened in the same tab. But, how to find if the user opens the link in a new tab/new window? Is there a way (other than IPC) in which we can find the url from which the user came from?

Thanks, 
simil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this cannot be done without using some form of IPC. Here is the same post on msdn [IE8 BHO C# tab problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/c5dd4337-8ae0-41d2-b8eb-6a8101203f6a/).